# Unable to use MS Access connection string

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Connection String for MS Access Database...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="immigration" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\agoyal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Immigration\DB\immigration.mdb;Integrated security=true" providerName="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I am getting the following error:

> An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

Comment: Connection String is::: **<add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=C:\\Users\\ankit\\Documents\\con.mdb;Integrated security=true" providerName="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"/>**

Comment: Take a look into this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fe60b72-0fe6-44ea-8486-438fb079d318/an-ole-db-provider-was-not-specified-in-the-connectionstring

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\agoyal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Immigration\DB\immigration.mdb;"
```